# How to overwrite the [] operator of a unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl

Would like to check if a key exists in a unordered_map.  Currently I use the `count()` member function. If it's greater than 0, that means the key exists.

Wonder if it's possible to do something like the following:

```
typedef std::unordered_map< long, long > m;
m[100] = 20;
m[1000] = 200;
...
//get user input x as an integer
if (m[x] == 0) {
    //do something
}
```

The problem with the above code is that, for a key `x` that doesn't exist,  `if (m[x] == 0)` will add an entry to the map.   What I need is, for the `[]` operator to return the default value (say "0" when the type is long, int,   empty string object if the type is string) if the key doesn't exist (just don't add an entry).  In my situation, the value of the unordered_map entries are not zero.  Don't know how to overwrite this operator.  Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: he can however inherit from unorder_map and override it. you can specify different spacename for so it will still have "unordered_map" as class name, but different spacename.

Comment: What is wrong with `count` member function?

Comment: You don't ever want to inherit from Standard containers. That's a tremendously bad plan.

Comment: @Puppy: Stop scaremongering. There is often, in fact, absolutely nothing wrong with inheriting from Standard containers.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.find()` instead. `if (map.find(key) != map.end())` then it exists in the map. Otherwise `if (map.find(key) == map.end())` it does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

> What I need is, for the [] operator to return the default value (say "0" when the type is long, int, empty string object if the type is string) if the key doesn't exist (just don't add an entry)

You could write such a function yourself - you don't need to override anything:

```
template <typename K, typename T, typename H, typename KE, typename A>
T value_or_default(const std::unordered_map<K,T,H,KE,A>& map,
                   const K& key,
                   T def = T{})
{
    auto it = map.find(key);
    return it != map.end() ? it->second : def;
}
```

Comment: wonder if it's possible to  overload the operator `[]`.  I tried to do `long operator [] (std::unordered_map< long, long > &m, long x) `, but the error shows operator [] has to be a member function.  Should I inherit from the class?   Thanks.

Comment: @codingFun I would just write the free function. Even if you wrote your own class, I still wouldn't overload `operator[]` to do this - I'd write a separate member function (e.g. [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) from Python is different than `dict.__getitem__`)

Comment: forget to mention that I got requirement that the recommended syntax is `[]`, that's what gives all the challenges :-(

Comment: @codingFun What can I tell you. Bad requirement.

Comment: Wish I could reject the requirement.  It comes from someone who knows scripting language, where this is trivial, but it's C++.

Comment: You forgot to std::move it.